# Why LED setting for android notification doesn't work

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to set the LED to a different color and speed for my notification it works on one device (running Lolipop) but not work on other device (running Marshmallow).

Can this be because the Android version or is my code setting incorrect?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(notify)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setTicker("Notification received")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, 250, 250)
            .setVibrate(pattern);
```

Please forgive me for my English and maybe improper question format.

Thank you very much for an explanation of my problem!

Comment: There is no guarantee that any particular device will even *have* a notification LED, let alone one where you can control the color. Beyond that, please explain in detail what "not work on other device" means.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. By 'not work on other device' I mean on my phone (real phone, no emulator) that runs lolipop my LED does what I ask it to in my code, but on my other device (also real phone) running marshmallow the LED blinks blue with normal pace same as other application notifications. I suspect android version has different rule for what I can do or can not do. Thank you again, your answer sheds light on my question for me.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code, though others might catch something that would help. Overall, do not assume that what you ask for in terms of `setLights()` and `setVibrate()` will be honored by all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue that was discovered long after the app was pushed to the users. As CommonsWare stated, I would highly recommend that you do not rely on the vibration or LED too heavily. You can use it, but don't use it as the primary feature that differentiates between notifications.

As for the reason why it doesn't work consistently, this is just normal Android behavior. Different manufacturers create their devices differently and code that is affecting hardware like this will not always provide consistent results.

I will say, however, that my particular issue was fixed by using:

```
notifications.ledARGB = 0xffffffff;
```

for a white LED. This is what worked for my Marshmallow version on a Galaxy S6 from AT&T while different code worked for my Note 3 Verizon device running Lolipop at the time. (I don't remember the exact code I used for that though).

Either way, try a few different things. You might have to do a version check in your code and code accordingly.

**Disclaimer:** I am no expert. I code as a hobby, so if someone else has a better answer and higher rep you will most likely want to go with their answer ;)